# "Object not supported" Javascript error trying to access FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

. .

I walked in this morning to find out that a calendar, implemented using FullCalendar and a public Google feed, is no longer working.  The calendar does not appear, and it gives me a Javascript error.

The Javascript error I'm getting is:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 13 Aug 2012 14:59:47 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 43
Char: 271
Code: 0
URI: http://[removed for security purposes]/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js
```

The original script code looked something like this:

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: false,
            events: '[Google feed removed for security]',
            className: 'gcal-event',
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                return false
                }
            });
```

(Disclaimer: I am not the original author of this code.)

This function used to work, and I haven't touched anything (other than trying out code to debug it -- which gives me the exact same error).  I'm trying to figure out what's changed.

To be honest, I don't think it's the Google data feed.  Reason: I copy/pasted the code from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ (for testing purposes), and I got the identical Javascript error.  Also, I tried going into the data feed URI, and it seems to come up fine.

The problem is not browser-specific; this problem appears regardless of whether I use IE, FF, Safari, Opera, etc.

It also doesn't appear to be user-specific; I've heard from at least two other users saying they have the same problem.

I'm running FullCalendar v1.5.3.

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Did you add the gcal.js script to your page?

Comment: do you have the http:// included in the link? Mine works fine

Comment: Which link are you talking about, the data feed or the script sources?  For the data feed, yes.  For the script sources, it's using the path relative to the root (starting with "/").

Comment: As I said before, this *used* to work.  I did not touch anything.  The other day, it just suddenly stopped working.

Comment: I was talking about the data feed. hmm... I'm not sure then, your code looks good to me and it seems to work on my side.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I'm scratching my head. Was wondering if anyone else had come across the same problem, and if they could give me an idea of where to look. I thought it might be an issue with the data feed, but (1) the data feed looks fine, and (2) I get the same problem if I change the events data.

Comment: @RayK. Any update on my solution did you tested it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

Apparently, it doesn't like the latest version of JQuery.

The script source is set to point to http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js.  Just for grins, I pointed it to the jquery-1.7.1.min.js that came with the FullCalendar code.

Lo and behold, it came right up.

**Edit:** I updated the references to appear as they do in the FullCalendar example, i.e.:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: For me updating to the latest version of jQuery-UI helped, (jquery-ui-1.8.23.min.js) instead of downgrading jQuery :)

Answer (score 8):

I think i got a way better answer :)

In fact is the `curCSS` function that has been removed with jQuery 1.8, it's actually been deprecated since 1.3.

The solution is to use `css` instead, so do a search & replace into the plugin replacing "curCSS" by "css"

And it will be all fine!

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11787

Comment: I'll give this a look when I have a chance.  At the time this came up, it was in production, so it was more important (at the time) that it was addressed quickly.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: yes i think you have no choice if you want to use the latest version of jQuery ;) But i'm 100% sure that will be the fix for you, you are welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

As curCSS was an alias for css you can add the code below to go around that issue.

```
if(!$.curCSS) 
    $.curCSS = $.css;
```