# Object doesn't support property or method curCSS - jquery 1.8.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi i am creating a form which allows the users to add friends to there list.. this pushes out a enter form when you press 'Add friends'. Now the form is working great except for it seems every-time i press 'Add Friend' it throws this error.. even though i know it should be working due to having this built before. Can anyone let me know what it is?

**This is the script line which is calling this jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Here the error:**

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'curCSS'
File: jquery-ui.min.js, Line: 357, Column: 143

**here is line 357:**

```
    q;else if(a.at[1]==="center")l.top+=q/2;l.left+=j[0];l.top+=j[1];
 return this.each(function(){var k=b(this),m=k.outerWidth(),o=k.outerHeight()
 ,p=parseInt(b.curCSS(this,"marginLeft",true))||0,s=parseInt(b.curCSS
 (this,"marginTop",true))||0,r=m+p+(parseInt(b.curCSS(this,"marginRight",true))
 ||0),u=o+s+(parseInt(b.curCSS(this,"marginBottom",true))||0),v=b.extend({},l),
 w;if(a.my[0]==="right")v.left-=m;else if(a.my[0]==="center")v.left-=m/2;if
 (a.my[1]==="bottom")v.top-=o;else if(a.my[1]==="center")v.top-=
```

You can see the 'curCss' in there but i dont know what i have to do to fix this problem?
Can anyone let me know whats i can do?

here is the none minimized version https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js

Thanks

Comment: first step - stop using a minified version of jQuery.  That'll make it easier to find out what `b` is supposed to be.

Comment: ok.. and the steps to fix this issue as it is now?

Comment: to take more steps, you must take the first step.  Also, use your JS console to find out what _your_ code was trying to do at this point.  The error is more likely a result of you passing bad data to jQuery UI than in jQuery UI itself.

Comment: here is the full version https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.js

Comment: I _know_ where the full version is!!  I already have a copy and cannot find the code corresponding to the part you have quoted.  You must load it on your site yourself and recreate the error so that you can tell which _exact_ unminified line the error is on.

Comment: [`curCSS` was removed from jQuery in version 8 apparently.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12100039/1377002)

Comment: @Andy good find.   OP - use earlier jQuery, or later jQuery UI.  Or just do `$.curCss = $.css` just after you load jQuery.

Comment: Updated it and it was fine thanks guys!!!